# Animation when I change a locale - framer motion

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

is it possible in Next.js that when I change a locale (i18n) to one to another there will be an animation?
I've tried Higher-Order Components but it doesn't work.
My HOC

```js
        import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
    import { chakra, shouldForwardProp } from '@chakra-ui/react'
    
    const StyledDiv = chakra(motion.div, {
      shouldForwardProp: prop => {
        return shouldForwardProp(prop) || prop === 'transition'
      }
    })
    
    const Section = ({ children, delay = 0 }) => (
      <StyledDiv
        initial={{ y: 10, opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.8, delay }}
        mb={6}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledDiv>
    )
    
    export default function WithAnimation(Component) {
      return props => (
        <Section>
          <Component {...props} />
        </Section>
      )

}
```

_app js

```js
//(...)
import Layout from '../components/layouts/main'
import WithAnimation from '../components/with-animation'
function Website({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  const { locale } = router
  const t = locale === 'en' ? en : pl
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Fonts />
      <Layout router={router}>
        <Component {...pageProps} key={router.route} />
      </Layout>
      <MessengerCustomerChat
        pageId="secretxxxxxxxxx"
        appId="secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        language={t.messengerChatLang}
        loggedInGreeting={t.loggedInGreetingLang}
        themeColor={t.themeColorLang}
      />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

export default WithAnimation(Website)
```

I render on my `Website` component with HOC `WithAnimation(Website)`

// update 1:
main.js (Layout component in _app.js)

```js
import NavBar from '../navbar'
import { Box, Container } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import Footer from '../footer'

const Main = ({ children, router }) => {
  return (
    <Box as="main">
      <NavBar path={router.asPath} />
      <Container maxW="container.md" pt={14}>
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </Container>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Main
```

I want to animate

```js
 <Container maxW="container.md" pt={14}>
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </Container>
```

when everytime a locale (i18n) is changed

Comment: what are you trying to animate, exactly?

Comment: The `{children}` inside `Layout` component (main.js - updated the code. Tt might be helpful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways to do that, but focusing on your case, you can add an `AnimatePresence` and use the `router.locale` as a trigger for the animation, like so:

```
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { chakra, shouldForwardProp } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const StyledDiv = chakra(motion.div, {
  shouldForwardProp: prop => {
    return shouldForwardProp(prop) || prop === 'transition'
  }
})

const Section = ({ children, delay = 0 }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <StyledDiv
      // pass the router.locale as the key, so every time it change it will trigger the animation
        key={router.locale}
        initial={{ y: 10, opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.8, delay }}
        mb={6}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledDiv>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}

export default function WithAnimation(Component) {
  return props => (
    <Section>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Section>
  )
}
```

I don't know if you already did that, but in your `next.config.js` you should add the locales:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en-US", "fr", "nl-NL"],
    defaultLocale: "en-US",
    domains: [
      {
        domain: "example.com",
        defaultLocale: "en-US"
      },
      {
        domain: "example.nl",
        defaultLocale: "nl-NL"
      },
      {
        domain: "example.fr",
        defaultLocale: "fr",
        http: true
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

it's just an example that i got from [nextJs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing), but it should work.

If you want to learn more about the `animatePresence` take a look at the [framer-motion docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/).

I'm also leaving a basic example with codesandbox, [check it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-ui-next-js-typescript-forked-2wbl4p?file=/pages/_app.tsx).

Comment: Just add `key={router.locale}` to my `AnimatePresence` in _app.js and it works flawlessly! Thank you !